# Problems using PolymerFire and Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, connection, polymer, firebase-storage, polymerfire

I'm building an app using PolymerFire, since PolymerFire doesn't features functionality to connect to Firebase Storage yet I'm facing some problems.

In my `index.html` file, I initialize the Firebase app using `<firebase-app>`:

```
<firebase-app
name="myApp"
api-key= "eriqujhiurehuioöwqoerghowöe4rqgeäfwh"
auth-domain= "myapp-123.firebaseapp.com"
database-url= "https://myapp-123.firebaseio.com"
>
</firebase-app>
```

The problem is, that I can't use `firebase.storage()` with this.

It looks like I have to add a second app initalization with the common configs:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

But this initializes the same app twice right? So this looks just wrong in my eyes.

I have somewhere deeper in my files tree a custom component which is supposed to upload images. I'm able to do so with the *two app init method* when it stands alone, but not when it's nested in the application.

It would take way too long to explain all the different variations I tried. So my question is, what's the best practice for connecting to Firebase Storage when using PolymerFire?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

**EDIT:**

I maged to get it work inside the application now with the *two app init method*, but this still feels wrong.

Comment: Also had this, managed to fix it though. How are you importing polymerfire?

Comment: @OlivierLangelaar I import polymerfire.html inside my app controller, import for  firebase-app.html is in index.html (installed with bower). <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">

Comment: Maybe try to include polymerfire.html, not sure if thats it but it includes all elements and behaviors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use:

```
<firebase-app
name="myApp"
api-key= "eriqujhiurehuioöwqoerghowöe4rqgeäfwh"
auth-domain= "myapp-123.firebaseapp.com"
database-url= "https://myapp-123.firebaseio.com"
storageBucket: "your_storageBucket"
>
</firebase-app>
```

because it's in the source code here:

https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/8568e28296d71bc508f57e32a2dfff5c2abe156d/firebase-app.html#L100

it's also in the docs:

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire?active=firebase-app

Comment: hello @OlivierKrull could you explain me what exactly the app="{{app}}" is bound to or what it is referring to ?! I am facing the same problem and I am unable to access the var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(); in Polymer

Comment: How do I use this to upload a file to the firebase cloud storage?